# Are WebApp IPs shared across Azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have two AppService plans each hosting a couple WebApps within my subscription that share the same public IP address.  I was just wondering if it was possible that someone else is also sharing that same IP, or are they different per subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service is a multi-tenant service, except for App Service Environments. It seems that the App service plan differs per a deployment unit. It does not matter with a different subscription.

In the same app service plan, the web app service is shared the same Inbound IP Address with other app services in that region. You can bind an IP-based SSL certificate to your App Service, which will give you a dedicated public inbound IP address. The outbound IP address of an App Service is not static, but it can be any address within a certain range, which is not static either.

Refer to [move an app to another App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan)

> Azure deploys each new App Service plan into **a deployment unit,
>   internally called a webspace.** Each region can have many webspaces, but
>   your app can only move between plans that are created in the same
>   webspace. An App Service Environment is an isolated webspace, so apps
>   can be moved between plans in the same App Service Environment, but
>   not between plans in different App Service Environments.

Answer (score 1):

Existing answer provides a lot of details but doesnt give a direct answer. Yes, this is a multi tenant service, there is such a possibility.